# How to connect .Net Core app to Azure SQL database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, azure

I have created an empty Azure SQL database.

I have added my IP to the firewall setting on the server.

I want EF Core to create the database for me with the command `dotnet ef database update`.

**I can successfully connect** to and query the Azure database via the `mssql` ext for **Visual Studio Code**.

I am have tried to connect the app to the database with connection strings as well as placing the connection string directly into the `Startup.cs` file.

**appsettings.json**

```
{
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
}
},
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Development": "Server=tcp:appName.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=AppName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=User;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
}
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        // Add database services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Development")));
    }
```

I run `dotnet restore` then `dotnet ef database update`

Finally, I get the following error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or 
was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that 
SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP 
Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
```

Am I missing something? What else can I try?

**EDIT :** I have even tried from a different location (different IP address). I added it to the firewall settings in Azure and **got the same results**. I can connect via the **mssql extension** in VSCode but not when I run the `dotnet ef database update` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `dotnet ef database update --verbose` revealed that the app was trying to connect to the default blogging.db database. I found that it was still listed in the `OnConfiguring` overridden function inside **ApplicationContext.cs**.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=blogging.db");
    }
```

After setting the proper database here everything started working.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a couple of things:

1. Make sure firewall **on your machine** allows outbound connections to 1433
2. Are you sure you used correct IP address in Azure Firewall rules? As a test, you can create a rule with ip range from 1.1.1.1 to 255.255.255.255 and see if it works. If it does, it means that you provided incorrect IP in Azure firewall

Comment: Thanks. Does this still apply even though I did connect through the mssql extension in VS Code as I mentioned in the post?

Comment: @BurningHippo, wait, you are totally correct. I missed that line. Is it possible that your connection string in appsettings.json has typos? Did you double check username/password/server/etc.?

Comment: @BurningHippo, it feels like EF picks up wrong connectionString for some reason.

Comment: no typos. I agree, but it's the same connection I used for mssql and that worked fine.

Comment: @BurningHippo, can you try to do this as a test:  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer( "Your_hardcoded_conn_string_here"));

Comment: That isn't working either. Maybe I have a faulty assumption of how the database connection works? Did I miss a step somewhere along the way? Is there a way to see what connection string `dotnet ef database update` is trying to use?